# ShouldComponentUpdate is never called in child components

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I've two components. One is parent (smart component that is connected to redux) and another is child component that is rendered in an iteration of array.

Whenever some redux action is dispatched from child component, the state in store is changed and whole list of elements is re-rendered but I want only to render the child that's actual state has been changed. Like in an array of locations, I want to show loader on a particular location and the object in array is updated well but why the shouldComponentUpdate is not available in child so that I can decide whether it should render or not.

**Parent Component**

```
import React                        from 'react';
import { connect }                  from 'react-redux';
import { createStructuredSelector } from 'reselect';

class Locations extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  render() {
    return this.props.locations.map((location) => 
    <Location
      toggleLocationStatusInfo={this.props.toggleLocationStatusInfo}
      location={location} />)
  }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({
  fetchLocations: (data) => dispatch(actions.fetchLocations(data)),
  toggleLocationStatusInfo: dispatch(actions.toggleLocationStatusInfo()),
});

const mapStateToProps = createStructuredSelector({
  locations: selectors.getLocations(),
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Locations);
```

**Child Component**

```
import React from 'react';
class Location extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  shouldComponentUpdate() {
    // THIS METHOD IS NEVER CALLED EVEN THE TOGGLE ACTION IS
    // DISPATCHCED AND REDUX STATE IS CHANGED. IT IS CALLED FINE FINE
    // PARENT (Locations) COMPONENT BUT NOT HERE
  }

  render() {
    // render this.props.location content here
    // One of my anchor calls onClick={this.props.toggleLocationStatusInfo}
  }
}

Location.propTypes = {
  location: React.PropTypes.object
  toggleLocationStatusInfo: React.PropTypes.func,
}
```

How can I find out why the shouldComponentUpdate is not called in children?

Comment: This is just a guess, but it might be because the Locations in the array don't have keys, so they're never actually getting _updated_ per se, just thrown away and rendered anew each time

Comment: Thanks a lot Hamms. That solved my problem.

Answer (score 3):

I forgot to add a unique key on each component, so it was just creating new children every time.

After adding key prop on Location, it worked fine.

Answer (score 2):

Same issue occurs if you are using Route from react-router and passing an inline function instead of a component, like so:

ISSUE

```
<Route
  path="/decrement"
  component={() => (
    <Decrement decrementBy={decrementBy} isLoading={isLoading} />
  )}
/>
```

SOLUTION

```
<Route
  path="/decrement"
  render={() => (
    <Decrement decrementBy={decrementBy} isLoading={isLoading} />
  )}
/>
```

or

```
<Route path="/decrement">
    <Decrement decrementBy={decrementBy} isLoading={isLoading} />
</Route>
```

Comment: Why isn't this answer at the top? Found this after searching for 5 hours and this worked like a charm.